# How to grab (orderId) payload value in form body to update the status of the order?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am working on mern stack e-commerce project . I have a order update route . Order status get updated only by the admin . While updating order status admin gets the default(preload) status . Then admin enter new status for updation .
When I enter (accept) into input fields and hit update button it shows this and status may not get updated .
I am not able to grab orderID .
[image]

[image]

**Here is my update status backend controller**

```
exports.updateStatus = (req, res) => {  Order.updateOne(
{ _id: req.body.orderId },
{ $set: { status: req.body.status } },
{ new: true, useFindAndModify: false },
(err, order) => {
  if (err) {
    return res.status(400).json({ error: "Cannot update order status" });
  }
  res.json(order);
} );};
```

**update order route**

```
 router.put(
  "/order-update/:userId",
  isSignedIn,
  isAuthenticated,
  isAdmin,
  updateStatus
);
```

**API handler for frontend**

```js
export const updateOrder = (userId, token, order) => {
  return fetch(`${API}/order-update/${userId}`, {
    method: "PUT",
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(order),
  })
    .then((response) => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
};
```

**Form for updating status**

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { isAutheticated } from "../auth/helper";
import Base from "../core/Base";
import { getOrder, updateOrder } from "./helper/adminapicall";

const UpdateOrder = ({ match }) => {
  const { user, token } = isAutheticated();

  const [status, setStatus] = useState("");
  const [error, setError] = useState(false);
  const [success, setSuccess] = useState(false);

  const preload = (orderId) => {
    getOrder(orderId, user._id, token).then((data) => {
      console.log(data);
      if (data?.error) {
        setError(data?.error);
      } else {
        setStatus(data.status);
        setError("");
        setSuccess("");
      }
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    preload(match.params.orderId);
  }, []);

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setError(false);
    setStatus(event.target.value);
    setSuccess(false);
  };

  const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setError("");
    setSuccess("");
    updateOrder(user._id, token, { status }).then((data) => {
      if (data?.error) {
        setError(true);
      } else {
        setError("");
        setSuccess(true);
        setStatus("");
      }
    });
  };

  const successMessage = () => (
    <div
      className="alert alert-success mt-3"
      style={{ display: success ? "" : "none" }}
    >
      <h4>updation successfull</h4>
    </div>
  );

  const warningMessage = () => (
    <div
      className="alert alert-success mt-3"
      style={{ display: error ? "" : "none" }}
    >
      <h4>updation failedl</h4>
    </div>
  );

  const orderUpdateForm = () => (
    <form>
      <div className="form-group col-md-6">
        <p className="lead">Update Order Status</p>
        <input
          type="text"
          className="form-control my-3 col-md-6"
          onChange={handleChange}
          value={status}
          autoFocus
          required
        />
        <button onClick={onSubmit} className="btn btn-outline-info col-md-6">
          Update Order
        </button>
      </div>
    </form>
  );

  return (
    //
    <Base title="Update Order Status" description="">
      {successMessage()}
      {warningMessage()}
      {orderUpdateForm()}
    </Base>
    //
  );
};

export default UpdateOrder;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to fetch orderId from the body but you are not sending OrderId in the body. Also, I am not able to understand why you sen UserId in route "/order-update/:userId".
I think you can send orderId as request param from the front end also you can update your route as

```
router.put(
  "/order-update/:orderId",
  isSignedIn,
  isAuthenticated,
  isAdmin,
  updateStatus
);
```

After that, you can get orderId as

```
  let { orderId } = req.params;
```

Comment: `router.put(
  "/order-update/:orderId",
  isSignedIn,
  isAuthenticated,
  isAdmin,
  updateStatus
)`   it not going to be work because /:userId in required because only admin is able to update order status

Comment: ```updateOrder(user._id, token, { status }).then((data) => {
      if (data?.error) {
        setError(true);
      } else {
        setError("");
        setSuccess(true);
        setStatus("");
      }
    });``` but from the front end, you are not passing orderId in the body also . You should have to pass it in body, so that you will get it in API controller.

Comment: Yeah .... I got that  ` const onSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setValues({ ...values, error: false });
    updateOrder(user._id, token, { status, orderId })
      .then(console.log(match.params.orderId), (data) => {
        if (data.error) {
          setValues({ ...values, error: data.error, success: false });
        } else {
          setValues({
            ...values,
            status: "",
            orderId: "",
            success: true,
            error: false,
          });
        }
      }) .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  };`